# Every X seconds get data from web

Tags: android, background

In my app, every 30 seconds I must reload content from web. The problem is that this function is working fine for a time, but after that (or when device is in stand by) the content is reload after 5 seconds, 7 seconds,..at different time moments and I don't understand why it is happen.

Here is my code :

on `onCreate()` method :

```
        handler1 = new Handler();
        t1 = new Timer();
        doReload1();
```

where `doReload1()` is :

```
public void doReload1() {

        scanTask1 = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler1.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Every 30 sec getPlaylist");                     


                    }
                });
            }
        };

        t1.schedule(scanTask1, 300, 30000);
        try {
            GetPlaylists(); //method for get data from web
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You are in catch");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do, is use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) since it will handle everything on your behalf needed to run the task while the phone is asleep. There is a demo of the use of this technique in the ApiDemos provided by Google.

In short though, you could have an IntentService catch the PendingIntent from the AlarmManager and then download the web data. Then, your Activity could grab this data whenever it wanted to refresh its data. Or, your service could send a signal to the Activity to actually update itself because new data is available.

**EDIT**

[Direct link to google example of using Alarms](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Alarm)

Comment: can you provide me a simple example? I found this http://android-in-practice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ch02/DealDroidWithService/

Comment: I added a direct link to the Google API demo. They are showing how to start a service and etc. Inside of AlarmService_Service, they are spawning a thread that does nothing. You could do the same thing, but actually perform your download in that task. Then maybe send a broadcast intent to your Activity to tell it to update itself. I would suggest using IntentService instead of a regular Service like google's example does so you don't have to spawn the thread yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Task in an Activity it will not work while phone is in standby mode. Make use of a service if you want data to be retrieved even while phone is standby.

Comment: Services also do not run while device is in sleep mode. You need to acquire WakeLock: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html